# iOS can't select segment in UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, arrays, header, tableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl in a headerview in a UITableView. For some reason, I cannot select any segments, whenever I do, it automatically selects the last segment in the array and I cannot select anything else. When I remove the action, I can select which ever. No idea what's going on.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section == 1) {

        UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 40)]; // x,y,width,height

        NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"E01", @"E02", @"E03", @"E05", @"E06", @"T05", @"E17", @"E19", nil];
        control = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
        [control setFrame:CGRectMake(30.0, 0, (tableView.bounds.size.width) - 60, 40)];
        [control setSelected:YES];
        [control setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStylePlain];
        [control addTarget:self action:@selector(unitSegmentControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        [headerView addSubview:control];

        return headerView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: what are you talking about? I didn't say anything to that nature?

Comment: oh, sorry. I wanted to write that to another question.

Comment: @JonErickson, Create `control = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];` in viewDidLoad or so and check this again. Also move `[control addTarget:self action:@selector(unitSegmentControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` to viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware what calling setSelected does on a UISegmentedControl, but I would suggest you use:

```
control.selectedSegmentIndex = anNSInteger;
```

to set the initial selected segment. I doubt that's your issue though.

Something else to consider if you have a scrolling table view,

```
viewForHeaderInSection
```

will get called for that section every time that header scrolls onto the screen, meaning that your segmented control will get reinitialized every time the header gets scrolled onto the screen, and you will lose your selected index.

Other than that maybe you could post the code for your unitSegmentControl selector. Possibly it's causing the table view to reload and your viewForHeaderInSection to be called again, thus reinitializing your segmented controller.

Comment: It is not a scrollable table, but I believe it has to do with GVUserDefaults. I was setting a property with each selected index, and I think it was causing it to reinitialize. So, I just went back to NSUserDefaults and am using that.

Comment: Yes, anything that causes your table view to reload will cause viewForHeaderInSection to be called again and reset your segmented controller. It might be a good idea to save the segmented controller elsewhere and just add it to your header view in the viewForHeaderInSection method instead of creating it there, depending on how your app works.

Comment: Well, to be honest, it wasn't being reloaded, because once you touched the segment, it would automatically select one you didnt choose, and it would stay selected and you wouldnt be able to unselect it or select another one, like it froze or something.